# Meaning of 'undoing the constitutional gains'?

Tags: meaning

> Based on the majority opinion, to what degree was the Supreme Court
>   responsible for **undoing the constitutional gains** of Reconstruction?

It's a question about Plessy v. Ferguson, and does this question mean "How much power does the Supreme Court have regarding canceling the constitutional amendment made during Reconstruction Era?"

I'm not sure if 'constitutional gains' means 'constitutional amendment', which refers to 13th, 14th, 15th Amendment.

Comment: Is this question from a graded work you have to complete? I ask because it seems to be a very specific and detailed question, reminiscent of one that would be formulated to test a student’s knowledge. Understanding the question would be a key part to demonstrating that you have acquired such knowledge.

Comment: @Paul Dirac I'm just reviewing the translation of this kind of text, and I'm not sure about its meaning so that's why I posted this question